# Finding first positive number and return a different correlating number

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a formula to find the first positive number in a data set, then return a correlating number assigned to that data. An example is I have 20 years' worth of Net Savings in column A, and their correlating Years in column B.

What formula would I use to return the year that sees the first net savings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,A2:A50000>0,0)+1)}
```

Please note, that you don't have to write `{}` when putting in the formula, this indicates, that this is an array formula, this means that when you enter the formula you have to submit (normally with enter) with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Side note, if you don't have Headers, then change A2 to A1 and delete the `+1`.